# Telegram PHP Bot - со временем начинает отвечеать с задержкой

Tags: php, api, telegram, бот

Есть Telegram PHP bot работающий по Webhook - функционирует корректно, однако после длительного использования "pending_update_count" - забиваются (сначала идет +1 -1, а после идет в большую сторону). Как пишет Telegram в getWebhookInfo принчина: "last_error_message": "Read timeout expired".

Вроде как причина может быть в том что Telegram(y) нужно ответить кодом 200, что ошибки нет, ну что то с этим пока не разобрался (не очень понимаю куда его прилепить).

Answer (score 1):

Все верно, если ваш бэкенд при вызове со стороны телеграма выдает ошибку, телеграм начинает реже отправлять запросы, чтобы совсем не убить ваш сервер. Код 200 никуда не нужно "прилеплять", это код ответа по-умолчанию, если в коде нет ошибки. Если код падает, сервер возвращает 500 код. Тогда и начинаются задержки.